# When was im2col first invented for use in CNNs?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

This one's a bit more of a historical question, but I don't know where else would be better than here.

Title's fairly self-explanatory - when was `im2col` first used for CNNs? From my scouring of the internet, the earliest I can date `im2col` itself is at least 2006: MathWorks claims the `im2col` function was provided at some point before the `R2006a` release on the documentation for `im2col`. It does not give any further specifics. Searching MathWorks' release history gives no further clues.

I'm more just curious than anything else - does anyone else have any idea?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: Before you do, and for those looking into this, where exactly would have been better to ask this?

Comment: Sorry, I am unable to suggest a better place.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: `im2col` existed way before CNNs were a thing. Convolutions have existed and used extensively way before as well. Typical of the “Deep Learning Generation” to think that everything that exists, exists for machine learning.

Comment: Well aware Cris, and agree on the latter point - my question was when `im2col` was first used in CNNs. And I think the answer is given below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think this is an interesting question that deserves to remain. While it's debated whether it stays, I'll post my findings here.

It appears the earliest known reference to 'unrolling' convolutional operations into matrix-multiplies ***for CNNs specifically***, was in 'High Performance Convolutional Neural Networks for Document Processing', by several Microsoft researchers way back in 2006. It is very clear from the figures provided that this is the `im2col` transform, although it was not specifically named as such - just 'unrolling'. Some of their terminology is also a bit old-fashioned by today's standards - strides are referred to in that paper as sub-sampling, so it seems pretty churlish to deny them the accolade based on not using the right name. Caffe developers wrongly claim that using `im2col` is the 'Caffe trick' - it is clearly not unique to Caffe, they didn't come up with it, and in fact this paper is referenced on their site.

It's worth noting that this was by no means the first usage of mat-muls for speeding up convolutions. The paper above specifically states "Simple unfolding of convolution is a well known technique. It is commonly implemented in signal processing and communications applications." It's pretty clear that the first usage of mat-muls for convolutions is likely to be much, much older than this, although the history on that remains a bit murky.

`gemm` as a routine was only formally introduced with BLAS level 3 in 1990, so it's possible that convolutions using mat-muls would have picked up considerably from then onwards due to the portability provided by BLAS. Of course, it's entirely possible - and likely - that earlier implementations would have used dedicated, non-standard matrix-multiply routines.